# Django Channels doesn't run basic test case

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-channels

I'm trying to test my consumers with the testing framework from django channels, but even a basic test doesn't seem to work

This is what my test case looks like:

```
from channels import Channel
from channels.test import ChannelTestCase, HttpClient, apply_routes
from rci.consumers import Demultiplexer
from rosbridge.consumers import OtherWebSocketConsumer

class ChannelTestCase(ChannelTestCase):

    def test_channel(self):
        client = HttpClient()
        client.send_and_consume('websocket.connect', '/new/') # <--- here's the error
        self.assertIsNone(client.receive())
```

This is my routing:

```
http_routing = [
    route("http.request", admin.site.urls, path=r"^/admin/", method=r"^$"),
    #...and so on
]

channel_routing = [Demultiplexer.as_route(path=r"^/sock/")]
```

This is my consumer:

```
class Demultiplexer(WebsocketDemultiplexer):
    channel_session_user = True

   consumers = {
       "rosbridge": ROSWebSocketConsumer,
       "setting": SettingsConsumer,
 }
```

This gives me the following error:

> ERROR: test_ros_channel
>   (robot_configuration_interface.tests.unit.test_channels.ROSChannelTestCase)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/cjds/development/robot_configuration_interface/robot_configuration_interface/tests/unit/test_channels.py", line 36, in test_ros_channel
>       client.send_and_consume('websocket.connect', '/new/')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/test/http.py", line
>   94, in send_and_consume
>       self.send(channel, content, text, path)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/test/http.py", line
>   79, in send
>       content.setdefault('reply_channel', self.reply_channel) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here:

> http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/testing.html#clients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### channels 1.x

You are calling `send_and_consume` with two positional arguments **which results in effect in this call** (which is exactly why there happens an **error** during execution in this line):

```
# AGAIN this is wrong code this is what is written in the question
# only difference is the naming of the (previously positional) arguments
client.send_and_consume(channel='websocket.connect', content='/new/')
```

and here is the explanation **why there is an error**:

However, the implementation of `send_and_consume` **expects `content` to be a dictionary**:

```
def send_and_consume(self, channel, content={}, text=None, path='/', fail_on_none=True, check_accept=True):
        """
        Reproduce full life cycle of the message
        """
        self.send(channel, content, text, path)
        return self.consume(channel, fail_on_none=fail_on_none, check_accept=check_accept)
```

Implementation code taken from: https://github.com/django/channels/blob/master/channels/test/http.py#L92

### channels 2.x

See https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html, as mentioned in the comment by Paul Whipp.

Comment: Marking this down for now because the answers wrong in many ways. For eg. `content='/new/'` is not correct but path='/new/' is would be correct. I appreciate the effort, and If you can incorporate https://github.com/django/channels/issues/586 into your answer and remove mistakes I'll mark it right

Comment: Well, if you could read the text around the wrong call you would understand that the line you complain about, especially `content='/new'` is *your* line of code, and - of course - it is wrong because `content` has to be a dictionary as I have already stated in my answer above.

Comment: @cjds: You should reconsider whats written in the answer, this looks correct to me!

Comment: Thanks @AmirHadi I didn't see the edit. Marking correct

Comment: This question and answer apply to channels 1.x. For 2.x see https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html